# Can a collection be a property in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to include a collection as a property in Neo4j?  And if so, would this be considered a schema that is in line with Neo4j's basic philosophy?

The fundamental reason I am interested in a node like this, is so that I can encode the idea of a sequence of actions. In this case, breakfast, lunch then dinner happened. I certainly don't want 3 separate nodes for each meal. Nor does it make sense to have 3 relationships that are meals, because they aren't going to connect to anyone.

I'm trying to develop something like this:

`CREATE (:Node {name: 'John Doe', food: [{breakfast: ['cereal', 'juice']},
                                           {lunch: ['sandwich', 'milk']}, 
                                           {dinner: ['M&Ms']}])`

All my attempts at something of this nature have led to these errors:

`Property values can only be of primitive types or arrays thereof`
or
`Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties.`

This lead me to believe that this type of structure is not a good idea, and I'm assuming there is a good reason why.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you want separate nodes for the meals?

Properties can be arrays of values.

You could just have 3 additional properties on your node (which acts as the map):

```
CREATE (:Person {name: 'John Doe', 
          breakfast: ['cereal', 'juice'], 
          lunch: ['sandwich', 'milk'], 
          dinner: ['M&Ms']})
```

You can also use `food.*` as property-names.

Comment: I do want that and I think it is great..but I'm also wondering why the other way isn't recommended? In general one of the useful things about key pair values is their nesting capabilities, no?

Answer (score 0):

1. No, nested collections as properties can not be used.
2. The philosophy is simple: maximum decomposition of objects and relationships to effectively use graph algorithms as a tool of analysis. Using your example with food:

   - Who eats the same foods for breakfast?
   - Who was the lunch at the same time?
   - What if you need to count calorie meal?
   - How different cooking methods of the same person on different days?
   - Who supplies these products?
   - In some recipes include these products?
   - What are the vegetables and fruit juices that people were in the day for breakfast?

And as an illustration of an exemplary model:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is about how Neo4j stores data. Here is an another way to see the error.

```
WITH {food: [{breakfast: ['cereal', 'juice']},{lunch: ['sandwich', 'milk']}, {dinner: ['M&Ms']}] }AS dailyDiet 
UNWIND dailyDiet.food AS diet
WITH {dietPlan: collect (diet)} as dailyDietPlan 
CREATE (n:DIET {name: 'John Doe', dailyFood : dailyDietPlan.dietPlan }) 
//RETURN dailyDietPlan.dietPlan AS dailyFood
```

The error appears:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.TypeError: 

Neo4j only supports a subset of Cypher types for storage as singleton or array properties. Please refer to section cypher/syntax/values of the manual for more details.
```

We can not create, by we can use RETURN for example, when we are retrieving data from JSON file. Here is an example from the file `nvdcve-1.1-2018.json` avaialable at [CVE JSON Feeds](https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-2018.json.zip).

```
{
  "CVE_data_type": "CVE",
  "CVE_data_format": "MITRE",
  "CVE_data_version": "4.0",
  "CVE_data_numberOfCVEs": "15976",
  "CVE_data_timestamp": "2019-12-11T08:25Z",
  "CVE_Items": [
    {
      "cve": {
        "data_type": "CVE",
        "data_format": "MITRE",
        "data_version": "4.0",
        "CVE_data_meta": {
          "ID": "CVE-2018-0001",
          "ASSIGNER": "cve@mitre.org"
        },
        "problemtype": {
          "problemtype_data": [
            {
              "description": [
                {
                  "lang": "en",
                  "value": "CWE-416"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "references": {
          "reference_data": [
            {
              "url": "http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/103092",
              "name": "103092",
              "refsource": "BID",
              "tags": []
            },
            {
              "url": "http://www.securitytracker.com/id/1040180",
              "name": "1040180",
              "refsource": "SECTRACK",
              "tags": ["Third Party Advisory", "VDB Entry"]
            },
            {
              "url": "https://kb.juniper.net/JSA10828",
              "name": "https://kb.juniper.net/JSA10828",
              "refsource": "CONFIRM",
              "tags": ["Mitigation", "Patch", "Vendor Advisory"]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

There are 15976 items in the actual file.

```
WITH "file:///nvdcve-1.1-2018.json" as url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
UNWIND  value.CVE_Items as cve
RETURN count (cve)

╒═════════════╕
│"count (cve)"│
╞═════════════╡
│15976        │
└─────────────┘
```

So, i try to extract only 5 records as follows:

```
WITH "file:///nvdcve-1.1-2018.json" as url 
CALL apoc.load.json(url) YIELD value 
UNWIND  value.CVE_Items as data
UNWIND data.cve.problemtype.problemtype_data AS cwe
UNWIND data.cve.references.reference_data AS references
UNWIND data.cve.description.description_data AS description
RETURN data.cve.CVE_data_meta.ID AS cveid, cwe.description[0].value AS cweid , COLLECT(references.url) AS references
LIMIT 5
```

And the output as shown below.

```
╒═══════════════╤════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"cveid"        │"cweid"         │"references"                                                          │
╞═══════════════╪════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"CVE-2018-0001"│"CWE-416"       │["http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/103092","http://www.securitytracker│
│               │                │.com/id/1040180","https://kb.juniper.net/JSA10828"]                   │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CVE-2018-0002"│"CWE-119"       │["http://www.securitytracker.com/id/1040178","https://kb.juniper.net/J│
│               │                │SA10829"]                                                             │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CVE-2018-0003"│"NVD-CWE-noinfo"│["http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/105715","http://www.securitytracker│
│               │                │.com/id/1040179","https://kb.juniper.net/JSA10831"]                   │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CVE-2018-0004"│"CWE-400"       │["http://www.securitytracker.com/id/1040183","https://kb.juniper.net/J│
│               │                │SA10832"]                                                             │
├───────────────┼────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"CVE-2018-0005"│"CWE-754"       │["http://www.securitytracker.com/id/1040182","https://kb.juniper.net/J│
│               │                │SA10833"]                                                             │
└───────────────┴────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I am clear that it will not solve your question, but it may give you a different perspective to think about how to store and retrieve the data in Neo4j.

happy :)  ~Neo-JSONing~